# Sending a php email with an attachment from a html form file upload

Tags: php, html

I know this is a very generic question but I need to make a online Time Card. And need a file Upload field. I know I need to make the input on the html side, but don't know what to do after that. I have worked with and sent php emails before but never with a file upload. So I basically Need to know where to go from there(how to code the php email sending part).I would really appreciate a very simple explanation and any help is very much appreciated.

Also I need it to send to the email that the employee lists. But I know that's part is very simple.

I have a live link that my client is currently using and they wanted me to add a file upload. If you have any questions please lmk.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


//email varible above to for order of operations reasons

$email = $_POST['email'];
$to = "example@123.com, $email";
$subject = "New TimeSheet";
$name = $_POST['employee'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$jobnum = $_POST['job#'];
$radio = $_POST['radiobtn'];
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$address = $_POST['location'];
$jobdes = $_POST['jobdescription'];
$starttime = strtotime($_POST['starttime']);
$lunchtime = $_POST['lunch'];
$stoptime = strtotime($_POST['stoptime']);
$totalhours = $_POST['totalhours'];
$drivetime = $_POST['drivetime'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];


$m1 = $_POST['m-1'];
$m2 = $_POST['m-2'];
$m3 = $_POST['m-3'];
$m4 = $_POST['m-4'];
$m5 = $_POST['m-5'];
$m6 = $_POST['m-6'];
$m7 = $_POST['m-7'];

$q1 = $_POST['q-1'];
$q2 = $_POST['q-2'];
$q3 = $_POST['q-3'];
$q4 = $_POST['q-4'];
$q5 = $_POST['q-5'];
$q6 = $_POST['q-6'];
$q7 = $_POST['q-7'];

$e1 = $_POST['e-1'];
$e2 = $_POST['e-2'];
$e3 = $_POST['e-3'];
$e4 = $_POST['e-4'];
$e5 = $_POST['e-5'];
$e6 = $_POST['e-6'];
$e7 = $_POST['e-7'];

$t1 = $_POST['t-1'];
$t2 = $_POST['t-2'];
$t3 = $_POST['t-3'];
$t4 = $_POST['t-4'];
$t5 = $_POST['t-5'];
$t6 = $_POST['t-6'];
$t7 = $_POST['t-7'];

$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" 

cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Tech Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$name. "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Job #:</strong> </td><td>" .$jobnum. "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Date:</strong> </td><td>" . $date . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Start Time:</strong> </td><td>" . date('h:i a', $starttime) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Lunch Duration:</strong> </td><td>" . $lunchtime . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Stop Time:</strong> </td><td>" . date('h:i a', $stoptime) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Total Hours:</strong> </td><td>" . $totalhours . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Drive Time:</strong> </td><td>" . $drivetime . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Job Complete:</strong> </td><td>" . $radio . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Customer:</strong> </td><td>" . $customer . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Location/Address:</strong> </td><td>" . $address . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Job Description:</strong> </td><td>" . $jobdes . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Notes:</strong> </td><td>" . $notes . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>FILE:</strong> </td><td>" . $file . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Materials:</strong></td> <td><strong>Qty:</strong></td> <td><strong>Each:</strong></td> <td><strong>Total:</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>$m1</td><td>$q1</td><td>$e1</td><td>$t1</td>";
$message .= "<tr><td>$m2</td><td>$q2</td><td>$e2</td><td>$t2</td>";
$message .= "<tr><td>$m3</td><td>$q3</td><td>$e3</td><td>$t3</td>";
$message .= "<tr><td>$m4</td><td>$q4</td><td>$e4</td><td>$t4</td>";
$message .= "<tr><td>$m5</td><td>$q5</td><td>$e5</td><td>$t5</td>";
$message .= "<tr><td>$m6</td><td>$q6</td><td>$e6</td><td>$t6</td>";
$message .= "<tr><td>$m7</td><td>$q7</td><td>$e7</td><td>$t7</td>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";



// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "From: forms@gradyelectricforms.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
$file = $_POST['fileupload'];

mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
header("location: http://www.gradyelectricinc.com",  true,  301 );  exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like what you want is to create a html form with inputs for client info, including a form they will upload. Not sure if you are planning to send that same (pdf?) file to the person submitting the form, that part isn't clear to me.

For email sending, I'd recommend using Sendgrid or Mailgun, these are SMTP services so that you don't have to use your own server for sending the emails. Many hosting providers, such as Google, prohibit SMTP sending from their servers so it's necessary to use a third party.

Along those lines, I'd recommend using [Sendgrid documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/) and grabbing PHP code directly from them. They have a [Github library for sending mail](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php), with examples to follow.

For uploading forms via PHP, you can also [search github for some helpful projects](http://Hi%20Mike,%20it%20sounds%20like%20what%20you%20want%20is%20to%20create%20a%20html%20form%20with%20inputs%20for%20client%20info,%20including%20a%20form%20they%20will%20upload.%20Not%20sure%20if%20you%20are%20planning%20to%20send%20that%20same%20(pdf?)%20file%20to%20the%20person%20submitting%20the%20form,%20that%20part%20isn't%20clear%20to%20me.%20%20For%20email%20sending,%20I'd%20recommend%20using%20Sendgrid%20or%20Mailgun,%20these%20are%20SMTP%20services%20so%20that%20you%20don't%20have%20to%20use%20your%20own%20server%20for%20sending%20the%20emails.%20Many%20hosting%20providers,%20such%20as%20Google,%20prohibit%20SMTP%20sending%20from%20their%20servers%20so%20it's%20necessary%20to%20use%20a%20third%20party.%20%20Along%20those%20lines,%20I'd%20recommend%20using%20[Sendgrid%20documentation][1]%20and%20grabbing%20PHP%20code%20directly%20from%20them.%20They%20have%20a%20[Github%20library%20for%20sending%20mail][2],%20with%20examples%20to%20follow.%20%20For%20uploading%20forms%20via%20PHP,%20you%20can%20also%20[search%20github%20for%20some%20helpful%20projects][3].%20That%20way%20you%20don't%20have%20to%20reinvent%20the%20wheel.%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/%20%20%20[2]:%20https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php%20%20%20[3]:%20https://github.com/search?q=uploading%20forms%20php). That way you can have a starting point.

I hope this gives you a few places to start.

Comment: Thank You good to know I will look in to those I updated my post with the link to the current timecard if you care to look at it.

Comment: No problem, if it's close enough to 'answering' your question, you could choose it as the answer. If not then perhaps you can share more details and I'm happy to assist further.

Comment: OK I see it there. thanks. So will they actually upload a file along with the entered form data? Or is the form data going to need to be build into a file?

Comment: Yes they will upload the form entries and the files. the employees will be uploading photos of the jobs they work on

Comment: Mike, OK. So try using some of the above links and see if you can figure it out. It sounds like you are on the right track. Incidentally I recommend using a framework for php development, like laravel. That way you can get some out of the box pieces already taken care of. But being I'm not sure if you are using something already, not sure what would work for you. Just a thought.